# Why doesn't creating file with echo work for remote directories in this script?

Tags: shell-script, directory, io-redirection, alias, echo

I aliased the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [[ -d "template.html" ]]; then
  :
else
  cp -n /home/$(whoami)/CS/Software/Pollen/template.html .
fi

/usr/bin/echo "#lang pollen



[1]: " > ${1}.html.pmd
```

with `alias tmd="~/CS/Software/Bash/create_md.sh"` in my `.bashrc`.
The script does its job of creating a file in the current directory but it fails to create a file in a distant directory, I get from Bash: `bash: /home/jim/CS/Software/Bash/create_md.sh: No such file or directory`. Quoting, i.e. `"${1}.html.pmd"`, has not resolved the matter. Yet `echo` typed in manually, e.g. `echo "ana-echo">ana1/ana2/file.html.pmd` does such job. Why is it so?
How might I improve on the script (so that it does the job in distant directories
as well)?

Comment: How do you run the script? What's the command? And what's the exact error message you get? Bash usually prefixes errors related to some file with the file name, doesn't that happen here?

Comment: @ilkkachu I run the script by typing its alias, e.g. `tmd ana1/ana2/file` where `ana1/ana2/` are the directories of the relative path to the file to be created  . The error message is `bash: /home/jim/CS/Software/Bash/create_md.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: The error msg edited in lately clearly indicates that with your suspicion (ana1/ana2/file) you're barking up the wrong tree. Your script is missing...

Comment: Or the `#!` on the first line of your script is funny.